# vs2010 : how to specify different files in 32-bit and 64-bit version of project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, project, masm

I am trying to build 4 versions of a 3D engine (in C/C++) with VS2010 (visual studio).  The versions are:

- 32-bit debug
- 32-bit release
- 64-bit debug
- 64-bit release

When I'm building the 32-bit versions, I need to include these files in my project:

- iceasm32.asm
- igasm32.asm

When I'm building the 64-bit versions, I need to include these files in my project:

- iceasm64.asm
- igasm64.asm

Each pair of 32-bit asm files contains the same functions as the 64-bit asm files, but obviously the 32-bit projects must contain only the 32-bit asm files, and the 64-bit projects must contain only the 64-bit asm files.

My problem is this.

When I add the 32-bit asm files to my 32-bit (win32) debug and release projects, then run the 32-bit debug and release versions of the program, they work.

Then when I switch the IDE over to the 64-bit (x64) debug and release projects, the 64-bit asm files are no longer part of the project, but the 32-bit asm files are!  So I exclude the 32-bit asm files from the 64-bit (x64) debug/release projects and add the 64-bit asm files, and then I can build and run those projects.

But then when I switch the IDE back to the 32-bit (win32) debug and release projects, they now contain the 64-bit asm files but not the 32-bit asm files!

Why is this happening?

Before my system disk crashed a while ago, I was developing this program with VS2005, and this problem did not exist.  I could have different files be part of the 32-bit and 64-bit projects, and they would "stay put".

Why is this not working with VS2010?

I doubt it matters, but I only have C/C++ installed with VS2010.  Not sure whether I had more than just one language with VS2005, but I only ever worked or programmed with C/C++.

Surely it is possible to have different sets of files for the 32-bit and 64-bit projects!  Right?

Comment: You have to add all files to the project, but can set an "Exclude from build" attribute on each individual file (and differently for each build type).

Comment: Where do I find "exclude from build"?  All I see is "exclude from project", but that excludes the file from all projects and builds.

Comment: Found it... but very obscure!  We should be able to right-click the file and find a "exclude from build" next to "exclude from project", but no.  We must right-click the file, select "properties", then find over near the top-right of the displayed dialog box where we can set "yes" or "no" for "exclude from build".  Very, very bad design.  Thanks for your help, Bo.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2015:
You can right-click the masm-file in the solutionexplorer and select properties of masm-file.
There you can specify for each config(debug, release, x86, x64) weather the file should be used.
The file remains in the solutionexplorer, but is used/not used for different
configs.